# Convert SQL query to Java Elasticsearch Query with grails plugin

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, grails, elasticsearch-plugin

How can I convert the following SQL query to Java Elasticsearch Query?

```
SELECT s.*
FROM supplier_detail_info sdi
JOIN supplier s ON sdi.supplier_id = s.id
JOIN supplier_detail sd ON sdi.supplier_detail_id = sd.id
WHERE (sdi.value = '70' AND sd.id = 1 ) OR (sdi.value = '46' and sd.id = 4);
```

I have tried the following (excluding the OR clause from above) but failed:

```
def query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().
                    must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery('supplierDetailInfos', QueryBuilders.matchQuery("supplierDetailInfos.value", '46')))
                    .must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery('supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail', QueryBuilders.matchQuery("supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id", 4)))
```

This resulted in:

```
{
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [ {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "match" : {
                "supplierDetailInfos.value" : {
                  "query" : "46",
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            "path" : "supplierDetailInfos"
          }
        }, {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "match" : {
                "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id" : {
                  "query" : 4,
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            "path" : "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail"
          }
        } ]
      }
    }
```

I'm using grails 2.3.7 and have the followings domains:

```
class Supplier {
    String name
    ....

    static hasMany = [supplierDetailInfos : SupplierDetailInfo]

    static searchable = {
        only = ['name', 'supplierDetailInfos']
        supplierDetailInfos component: true
    }
}

class SupplierDetailInfo {
    SupplierDetail supplierDetail
    Supplier supplier
    String value

    static searchable = {
        only = ['id', 'supplierDetail', 'value']
        supplierDetail component: true
    }
}

class SupplierDetail {
    String name
    ....

    static searchable = {
        only = ['id']
    }
}
```

I'm using elasticsearch 2.3.5 and the elastic search plugin "org.grails.plugins:elasticsearch:0.1.0".

From what I understand,

> must is equivalent to AND

&

> should is equivalent to OR.

The above query should have returned only those suppliers for which the value of supplier_detail_info is '46' when the supplier_detail id is 4. But it returns all suppliers for whom there exists a supplier detail info with value '46'. It simply ignores the 'and sd.id = 4' part of the query. Also, I cannot figure out how to use the OR part.

Comment: Post your mapping and the error msg you are getting

Comment: @sramalingam24 I'm not getting any error message.

    {"query": {"nested" : {"query" : {
      "match" : {
        "supplierDetailInfos.value" :"46"
      }
    },
    "path" : "supplierDetailInfos"}
    }
    }
This gives me 7 hits

{
"query":
{
  "nested" : {
    "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id" :4
      }
    },
    "path" : "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail"
  }
}
}
This gives he 332 hits. I need the intersection of the two - 4 hits.
But combining the 2 also gives 332 hits.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a bool query try a nested query with a bool inner query and two must clauses. Also I think that the match queries should be term queries as they seem like keyword/long fields and not text fields and if you want OR make the must a should clause

```
{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "path":"supplierDetailInfos",
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "supplierDetailInfos.value":"46"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "match":{
                        "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id":4
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sramalingam24. The problem here is that supplierDetailInfos.value is on path supplierDetailInfos, but supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id is on path supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail. So the above query resulted in 0 hits. Is it possible to have ANDing of nested query on different paths?

Comment: Hmm, nested query does support multi-level nesting, so I suppose you can wrap the second match clause above within another nested query ( not sure about version 2.3.5 though)

Comment: Thanks @sramalingam24. Your answers gave me enough hints to explore further. I have now answered my question :)

Comment: Good deal amigo!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem thanks to @sramalingam24.
The elasticsearch query can be written as follows:

```
{
"query":{
  "nested":{
     "path":"supplierDetailInfos",
     "query":{
        "bool":{
           "must":[
              {
                 "match":{
                    "supplierDetailInfos.value":"46"
                 }
              },
              {
                 "query":{
                    "nested":{
                       "path":"supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail",
                       "query":{
                          "bool":{
                             "must":[
                                {
                                   "match":{
                                      "supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id":4
                                   }
                                },

                             ]
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
 }
}
```

The equivalent query can be written using QueryBuilders as follows:

```
def supplierDetailQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
def supplierDetailIdQuery = QueryBuilders.nestedQuery('supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail',
                QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("supplierDetailInfos.supplierDetail.id", id)))
def supplierDetailIdAndValueQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("supplierDetailInfos.value", value))
                .must(supplierDetailIdQuery)
supplierDetailQuery.must(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery('supplierDetailInfos',
                supplierDetailIdAndValueQuery))
```